# Python и ОС Linux

Tags: python

Привет!

Интересует следующий вопрос. Если написанный на Python проект собрать, допустим через Pyinstaller (он поддерживает Линукс, судя по заявлениям разработчиков) в ОС Ubuntu. Смогу ли я использовать его на Centos допустим в дальнейшем?

P.C Не спрашивайте, пожалуйста, почему сразу не собрать ни Centos.

Comment: сделайте пакет .deb для Ubuntu и .rpm для CentOS, пользователи вам спасибо скажут, и не будут поминать ваше имя плохим словом.

Comment: @Vladimir Gordeev как собрать из проекта на Питоне .deb и .rpm я абсолютно не знаю. Знаете ли вы ресурс, где об этом можно было бы прочитать?

Comment: @Sever, а просто tar-ом Ваш проект поставить невозможно?

Comment: @avp Тут дело в том, что у проект использует большое число, различных модулей Питона. И допустим, если мне самому надо установить проект на другой сервер, я должен в начале установить все используемые модули для питона и только потом смогу запустить. В принципе Pyinstaller мне не помог. Все что я хочу сделать это просто собрать проект так, чтоб все необходимые модули питона устанавливались, вместе с ним (неважно хоть tar, хоть zip).

Comment: Если ваш проект использует стандартную библиотеку классов питона, и никаких отдельно поставленных библиотек, просто тар архив гзипованный сделайте, и не парьтесь. Если он у вас использует какие-либо дополнения, то не знаю. Возможно, setuptools сможет вам помочь

Comment: @nolka все дело в том, что использует много сторонних модулей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для Linux посмотрите пакет "pyfreeze".
Для Windows есть аналог - "py2exe".
На сколько я помню, эти пакеты, как раз, собирают все используемые в коде модули и создают инсталятор.

Comment: Про py2exe слышал, а вот про pyfreeze нет. Попробую, отпишу, благодарю.

Comment: Если честно, про pyfreeze ничего не нашел. Скорее всего вы имели ввиду http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze. Я однако не успел до него добраться, т.к наткнулся на cx_Freeze, о котором знал, но относился скептически, но тем не менее решил попробовать и он собрал весь проект за считанные секунды. И что самое важное, он работает. Хотя в нем используется много-много модулей перемешанных между собой. Я только теперь протестирую его на нескольких ОС (с и без питона). Спасибо вам и ребятам выше, любезно откликнувшихся на мой вопрос.

Comment: могу принять участие в тестировании

Answer (score 5):

Стандартом для распространения проектов на Python являются пакеты-яйца. Зависимости указываются в `setup.py` в параметре `install_requires`. Когда кто-нибудь скажет `pip install .` (или имя на PyPI, или URL откуда можно скачать тарболл), то все зависимости будут увидены и подтянуты. [Процесс создания пакета](http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html) очень детально расписан в документации `distribute`. Не забывайте совмещать с virtualenv (или ключом `--user` для pip, чтобы тот ставил в `$HOME`) для лучшего эффекта.

Если Вы хотите собрать «родной» пакет для какого-либо дистрибутива (например, Debian), то тут возни больше — каждый пакет, которого нет в репозитории, придется упаковать, ручками повозившись с `debian/*` (или, соответственно, `*.spec` для RPM, `*.ebuild` для Gentoo, `PKGBUILD` для Arch и т.д.). Руководства для мейнтейнеров конкретных дистрибутивов в помощь.

Сборка с pyfreeze — это как статически слинкованные бинарники. Можно, и даже будет работать, но это максимально неродное для любой системы решение. Далее чем «строго для себя» не рекомендовал бы. Хотя даже «для себя» мне кажется, проще написать тривиальный `setup.py` и пользоваться.

Comment: Я с Вами согласен. Я как раз разбираюсь с этой темой. Спасибо, так подробно описали.